# Installing pip package with ansible in virtualenv need to use pip3?

Tags: pip, ansible

basically here is my role

```
---

- name: pip install mimodd {{ version }}
  pip:
    name: mimodd
    version: "{{ version }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ apps_dir }}/mimodd-{{ version }}"
    virtualenv_python: python3.5
    virtualenv_site_packages: yes

  tags: mimodd

- file:
    dest: "{{ modules_bio }}/mimodd-{{ version }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755

  tags: mimodd

- name: mimodd {{ version }} module definition
  template:
    src: sw-module.lua.j2
    dest: "{{ modules_bio }}/mimodd/{{ version }}.lua"
    owner: "{{ main_guy }}" 
    mode: 0644
  with_items:
    - dir: 'mimodd-{{ version }}'
      help_text: 'loads mimodd pipeline'
      append: true 

  tags: mimodd
```

and here is my error, so obviously it is using pip2 ! How do I make it to use pip3 ?

```
   fatal: [biotraining-bak]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/local/bin/pip2 install mimodd==0.1.7.3", 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null, 
            "editable": true, 
            "executable": null, 
            "extra_args": null, 
            "name": [
                "mimodd"
            ], 
            "requirements": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "umask": null, 
            "use_mirrors": true, 
            "version": "0.1.7.3", 
            "virtualenv": "/software/apps/mimodd-0.1.7.3", 
            "virtualenv_command": "virtualenv", 
            "virtualenv_python": "python3.5", 
            "virtualenv_site_packages": true
        }, 
        "module_name": "pip"
    },
```

I tried `executable: pip3` but get this error

```
"msg": "parameters are mutually exclusive: ['executable', 'virtualenv']"
```

**Extra information**

ansible version

```
[biostation]~$ ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = 
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

targeting ubuntu 16.04 and linux in general

Comment: why would you mark down this question without a reason? is this a stupid question? or is the answer very very obvious? Well mister smarty pants educate me!

Comment: just update question to reflect your comment @techraf

Comment: it came with it I'm pretty sure

```ubuntu@biotraining-bak:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
ubuntu@biotraining-bak:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python```

Comment: I'm confident, these are the only python packages I installed ```python-pip python3-pip python-dev```

Comment: @techraf mate honestly if don't know how to communicate then don't. There is no use sending me random link to a comment in the file. If i wanted to read ansible source and figure our pip issue I would have done so. So clearly there is a bug or an issue in ansible, which is what you are eluting to. Do you have a solution or work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use **virtualenv_command**

```
- name: Create virtualenv for Python-{{ version }}
 pip:
   name: mimodd
   virtualenv: "{{ apps_dir }}/mimodd-{{ version }}"
   virtualenv_command: "virtualenv-{{ version }}"
```

[ansible pip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/pip_module.html)

Comment: thanks for the comment, I got that sorted shortly afterwards after I posted this question, but just looked at the solution and turns out that this is exactly what i did ha! I think its worth while accepting this question, cheers